# jQuery: how do i search for a specific ID tag and create that element?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, how do I search the DOM for a specific element tag by ID and create that element if the tag ID is not found?

Here is the element to be created if tag is not found:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!$('#foo').length){//if the element does not exist    
  $('<div id="foo"/>')//create it
   .appendTo('#something');//and inject it to the DOM
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perfect solution
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/element-exists/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (!$('#foo').length) { // implies *not* zero
    $('#MyParentDiv').append('<div id="foo"></div>'); // add the element
  }
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/yaxzz/1)